# <p> tag has padding around it

Tags: html, css, django, forms

I have form with multiple inputs in it:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="First name" class="input_1_error input_1">
<input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="input_2" name="last_name" size="1" value="{{ data.last_name }}">
<input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="input_3" name="username" size="1" value="{{ data.username }}">
<input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="input_6 input_6_error" name="email" size="1" value="{{ data.email }}">
```

but when I add
`<p>Please enter your email</p>` under email it creates much more space than I would want

Comment: you can remove the padding using css. although personally I think it's margin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's margin not padding and you can change its value to achieve your desired space using CSS.

for example this is your p element:

```
<p class="paragraph">Please enter your email</p>
```

you can set your desired value for its margin like this:

```
.paragraph {
  margin: <top> <right> <bottom> <left>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe u can try this

```html
<p>Please enter your email:<input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="input_6 input_6_error" name="email"></p>
```